Ubuntu 22 SMB Share + Windows 10 Password Error
I've set up a Linux computer with an SMB share according to this tutorial: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-samba-share-on-ubuntu-server-20-04/
Added and enabled a user with
sudo smbpasswd -a christian.disch
sudo smbpasswd -e christian.disch
On my windows laptop, I try to connect to the share:

But then I am prompted with this:

I'm fairly certain that I use the correct password. What I am doing wrong?

If you are tryinf to connect to the SAMBA share from Windoze, you need to read this article
